# Windows 10 stuck at Please wait blue screen, wont go into login screen

Tags: windows-10

I was using my laptop Saturday morning and left it on while I was. When I came back it was at the login screen which meant that it had restarted at some point. I logged in and the **Task Bar was frozen**. It had previously done the same thing the previous day, Friday, of restarting itself and when I logged in then, the **desktop was just black**, but the icons where visible and working, when I tried to right click on the desktop and go to the Personalize setting there was an error, **there is no app associated with that function**. The following day the problem with the Task Bar started. So the desktop was now black and the Task Bar frozen but I could still access the icons.

I decided to use the command shutdown -s to shut it down. While it was on the process of shutting down, a Blue Screen of death appeared with the error **Kernel Data In-page Error**, mind you it was not the first time getting this error and my computer never had any problems. Upon restarting my PC just got stuck at a blue screen written Please Wait with the spinning dots. The login screen never coming up. The cursor was visible but nothing happened.

So this is what I tried.

1. I tried using the **Restore Point** from recovery options. It failed saying that the restore point was corrupted. The restore point was after a security update done on Friday and for some reason it was the only restore point there.
2. I tried **Startup Repair** and it failed.
3. I tried the **Revert To a Previous Windows Build** and it failed saying there was nothing.
4. I tried **Safe Mode** and it too got stuck at the Please Wait screen with the spinning dots.
5. I ran **chkdsk** at the command prompt in recovery options and it said everything was fine.
6. I try running **sfc /scannow and DISM** and they failed to run citing errors.

I haven't tried the **Reset option** as I wasn't sure if it would revert me to windows 8. I upgraded to windows 10 from 8 using the free upgrade that was rolled out by Microsoft.

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Black Screen with no ability to Personalise is an authorisation error. That on its own wouldn't really be a worry, you could always re-authorise with MS.
The rest of the information, though, would say either virus infection or failing hard drive. I'd say the more you try to fix it at this stage, the less the chance of data recovery later.

I think your best approach right now is to boot from a unix recovery disk/USB key & dd the data over to a spare drive, which can then be examined for infection/data loss, without further upsetting the original disk.